# Lossless Video Streaming with FFmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-streaming

I am looking stream video (likely with udp) between two instances of ffmpeg, without having any potential quality loss due to encoding. I am not too worried about bandwidth, I just want the stream to be real time and of the same quality as the input. The two main approaches that I have tried so far are encoding with `huffyuv` and using `rawvideo`. I have been able to encode with both options writing to a file that plays back fine, but I have not been able to create a stream that I can open with either. I have also seen that `x264` has a lossless encoding option, however due to licensing constraints that isn't a great option for me.

Here are my successful command lines writing out to a file:

```
ffmpeg -i /dev/video0 -c:v huffyuv -f avi out.avi
ffmpeg -i /dev/video0 -c:v rawvideo -f nut out.nut
```

Here are my not so successful streaming attempts:

```
ffmpeg -i /dev/video0 -c:v huffyuv -f udp://239.255.76.67:1130?ttl=1
ffmpeg -i /dev/video0 -c:v rawvideo -f nut udp://239.255.76.67:1130?ttl=1
```

Then trying to stream I have tried having the receiving instance both auto detect and force streaming format:

```
ffplay udp://239.255.76.67:1130
ffplay -f avi -vcodec huffyuv udp://239.255.76.67:1130
ffplay -f nut -vcodec rawvideo udp://239.255.76.67:1130
```

For all of those combinations I get the same error:

```
udp://239.255.76.67:1130: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you start your receiving instance before starting the serving instance, you can use

`ffmpeg -i /dev/video0 -c:v huffyuv -f avi udp://239.255.76.67:1130?ttl=1` or nut, flv, matroska in place of avi. You won't be able to stop and restart the receiving instance.

If you need to accommodate a late start by the receiving instance or restarts, then you have to use a streaming format like mpegts. MPEG-TS does not support huffyuv or rawvideo. You're stuck with H.264/5 then.

Receiving instance is simply `ffplay udp://239.255.76.67:1130`